# Set number of copies per worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, printing

I have a workbook that combines multiple reports. Currently, I am using a piece of vba code to determine which worksheets are printed based on a cell value in each worksheet.

Is there a way to add to the existing code to set each worksheet to print a specific number of times per sheet? example, print sheet1 2 times, print sheet2 1 time, and so on, using a cell reference on that worksheet. The code

I have for printing so far is:

```
Sub PrintSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim arrWS()
Dim I As Long
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Range("A1") = "print" Then
            ReDim Preserve arrWS(I)
            arrWS(I) = ws.Name
            I = I + 1
        End If
    Next ws

    Sheets(arrWS).PrintOut
End Sub
```

I've tried a couple different items, but they each look to one sheet to determine how many times everything is printed, instead of allowing each page to have its own specific number of copies.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at Omar's answer and my previous answer, I think you don't need an array at all. Put the number of copies you want to print on each sheet in Cell A2:

```
Sub PrintSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Range("A1") = "print" Then
        ws.PrintOut Copies:= ws.Range("A2").Value2
    End If
Next ws


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sheets(arrWS).PrintOut Copies:=Range("A2").Value
```

Comment: This answer is great, much better than my previous attempt, but I think it is still incomplete as far as efficiency so I am going to combine your answer into mine and make a final change. Good work!