# Restrict number of copies to print

Tags: excel, printing, vba

I have 5 computers and two printers connected by LAN. There is one particular excel document in one of the computers (not shared) for which I wish to restrict the number of copies that can be printed, to 4. Meaning the user should not be able to print more than 4 copies of that document.

I am aware of the photocopying (and more) loopholes, but i am still hopeful of print copies getting out in a controlled or limited number.

I have looked through the features of a few print control softwares, but i learnt that they all have a "quota" system with users having to pay for printing after exceeding their limit. I am afraid this wont work for me.

I also read an answer to a similar question posted here, [Set number of copies per worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171316/set-number-of-copies-per-worksheet)

Thankfully this answer very much helped me, except I have no clue on how am going to restrict or limit the user to take printouts beyond the specified number.

I also have read many answers saying that restricting the number of copies is next to impossible, But i still wish to look for help - maybe some solution could come up.

I dont have much deep knowledge in computer/printer programming.Though not a pro, I am a little familiar with excel vba.

Please let me know if there can be any solutions,

As soon as I find something I'll post it here.

Thanks a ton for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a crude solution but this would add *some* limit on number of prints...

Place in `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)    
    Cancel = True  
    If Cancel = True Then
        MsgBox "Please use the print button on Sheet1."
    End If   
End Sub
```

Add a `CommandButton` and rename it `PrintButton` then insert this subroutine (and accompanying functions) into a `Module`

```
Private Sub PrintButton_Click()
  On Error Resume Next
    Application.EnableEvents = False

        If (CanWePrint(4)) Then
           ActiveSheet.PrintOut
        Else
            MsgBox ("Sorry this is the maximum number of prints for this document!")
        End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub


Function CanWePrint(ByVal MaxPrintVal As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim CurrentPrintCount As String, SecretFile As String

    'PLEASE CHANGE TO YOUR "SECRET" TXT FILE NAME AND LOCATION!
    SecretFile = "C:\Users\Matt\Documents\countPrint.txt"

    CurrentPrintCount = GetCount(SecretFile)

    If (CurrentPrintCount < MaxPrintVal) Then
        Call UpdatePrintCount(CurrentPrintCount, SecretFile)
        CanWePrint = True
    Else
        CanWePrint = False
    End If

End Function

Function GetCount(ByVal SecretFile As String) As Integer

   Dim nSourceFile As Integer
   Dim sText As String

   Close

   nSourceFile = FreeFile

   Open SecretFile For Input As #nSourceFile
    sText = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
   Close

   GetCount = CInt(sText)

End Function

Sub UpdatePrintCount(ByVal CurrentVal As Integer, ByVal SecretFile As String)

    Dim sBuf As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim iFileNum As Integer

    iFileNum = FreeFile
    Open SecretFile For Input As iFileNum

    Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
        Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
        sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
    Loop
    Close iFileNum

    sTemp = Replace(sTemp, CurrentVal, CurrentVal + 1)

    iFileNum = FreeFile
    Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum

    Print #iFileNum, sTemp

    Close iFileNum

End Sub
```

#### What this does

This code will disable the standard Print option in Excel for that workbook. By adding a `CommandButton` you create a manual print option which will check the print count stored in a `.txt` file, this will mean the document can be closed and reopened and still only be printed 4 times.

#### What you need to do

- Create a new txt file on the same machine as this document and update the path in code above in `CanWePrint`.

#### Draw Backs

Like I said this is a crude solution and there would be many ways around this:

- Manually change the value in the `.txt` file
- Save the workbook without VBA
- Disabling the VBA

Comment: Thankyou so much Matt!

Comment: @seepra you're welcome. Don't forget to mark the question as complete if this solves your problem! :-)

Comment: Yes, please do have a look at my answer and let me know if it is good enough, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is not at all crude, its very much sophisticated for me:) I am okay with the drawbacks mentioned. The code worked fine when i pasted it in sheet 1 instead of a module. Theres one catch here though, Matts code is good for one file..what i have is an empty template like file(saved as macro enabled excel workbook, but working like a template for me) which has to be filled up and printed again and again, but I need to avoid duplication, hence not more than 4 copies.

So what i have tried is, 
i created a macro with a keyboard shortcut. This macro does this:

1. It takes 4 printouts.
2. It inserts a watermark into the file, (thus marking it as invalid)
3. It exports the selected range as pdf and saves it in my specified folder (so  all saved pdfs have watermarks, and its not possible to erase it in adobe reader)
4. It removes the watermark, clears all entered data, thus providing a new doccument to be created next time.
   This is working for me, except that anyone could print any number of copies if they did not use my shortcut.
   But with the "beforeprint" code in Matts answer that will be solved.
   So thanks a ton Matt!
   As you mentioned, there can be more ways around this, I'll keep working, 
   For now this should work for me.

Please let me know if my way is good and if there are any loops..
Thank you!